# Figuring out apple time

Tags: big-o

I am fairly new to big-o and i'm trying to figure out what the big o running time is for this small section of code. I know that usually if there i but does the whole array thing change anything? I'm fairly confused so any bit of input would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
public apple(int n)
{
    int n = 0;
    int apple = 0;
    a = apple + n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When determining algorithmic complexity in terms of Big Oh Notation, the most dominant term is used to determine the complexity. Although the complexity of this algorithm in detail could be said to be 1 + n + n + 1, the complexity of it is O(2n) because that is the sum of dominant terms.

If the complexity in an arbitrary algorithm was 2 + 5n + n*n then the the complexity would be O(n^2) where n was > 5. otherwise it'd be 5n